# formatting x-axis labels in highchart

Tags: highcharts, format, label, formatter

I'm just wondering can anyone tell me how I'd go about formatting my x-axis labels on my highchart?
I've set min:0 and max:300 but I want to trim the last digit on the min and max. i.e 280 would become 28.

The code I thought would work was:

```
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                 return this.value.substring(0, 3);
            }
        }
```

But that seems to crash the highchart. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`this.value` is a number, not a string.  You could convert to a string and then take a substring.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return  this.value.toString().substring(0, 2);
        }
    }
},
```

But, it's not a very robust solution.  If your numbers grow above 999, you'll still only get the first 2 digits.  I think you'd be better off with something like this:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
           // return  this.value.toString().substring(0, 2);
           return Math.round(this.value/10);
        }
    }
},
```

Also, be aware that you will have to do this same transformation to tooltips and point labels.  It might make more sense to transform your data, than to transform all the ways highcharts talks about your data.

http://jsfiddle.net/3y8dnh5u/2/